# How to fetch data from four tables using SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've four tables namely registry_item , publish_registry , registry_user and premium_user. I want to get all items from registry_item table where user status is 1 in publish_registry table and user is not older than 7 days in registry_user table or user is premium user in premium_user table. I've tried this

```
SELECT * FROM publish_registry pr 
JOIN registry_item ri USING ( registry_id ) 
JOIN premium_user pu USING ( registry_id ) 
JOIN registry_user ru USING ( registry_id ) 
WHERE ri.category_id = '2' AND pr.status = '1' 
 AND ru.date_added > NOW() - 7 OR pu.registry_id = ru.registry_id
```

Comment: show what have you tried.

Comment: You will have to show your table structures.

Comment: Be careful to put your OR'd condition in parentheses. I suspect that's how the last two conditions were meant to be.

Comment: I am getting same data if category_id is changed. If i set category_id to 3 then also its showing data of category_id 2

Comment: Like @shawnt00 said watch your `OR` condition in conjunction with multiple `AND` should be something like `ri.category_id = '2' AND pr.status = '1' AND (ru.date_added > NOW() - 7 OR pu.registry_id = ru.registry_id)` depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer with very less information and as others said please show what you have done,so that others can rectify your answer, seeing at your question i assumed this might help you to understand what you are looking for(nearest answer). But i haven't used join statements.

```
select * 
from registry_item ri,public_registry pr,registry_user ru,premium_user pu
 where 
    ri.primary_key=pr.foreign_key and pr.user_status=1 and
    ri.primary_key=ru.foreign_key 
    and ru.user_date < DATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), interval 7 Day))
    AND ri.primary_key=pu.foreign_key and pu.user = 'premium';
```

If it's helpful then great!! or state more info about your work so that we can help. :)